# The $\Delta$-complex: Is it just a set containing $\{\Delta_i\}_{i=0}^n$(with identifications)?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplex, simplicial-complex

I would like some clarification on the idea of a $\Delta$-complex:

It seems that we can identify edges of a triangulated polygon to obtain $2$-dimensional spaces and the idea of a $\Delta$-complex is to break any object up into simplices of various dimensions identifying $n$-cells. A $\Delta$-complex then is a collection $\{\Delta_0,\Delta_1,\Delta_2,\cdots,\Delta_n\}$ where identify basis elements of these $\Delta_i$ with other elements within the same $\Delta_i$. Where the basis elements are the $i$-cells of the complex?

Could someone check this for misunderstandings? I am mainly worried about how the latter seems to feel pinned on only being relevant to a single $n$-simplex, whereas I feel the $i$-cells shouldn't be identified away from a single $n$-simplex, where more than one may exist in the $\Delta$-complex (right?)

Comment: For example, for $X$ being a $3$-dimensional cube(i.e. not the shell of the cube, but containing the $3$-cell), I would need to break this into two $3$-simplices right. In that case I wouldn't need to identify edges, but say I was dealing with another topological space, and I had the two tetrahedrons above, would I be able to identify edges *between* the two? Say these $3$-simplices were $A,B$ can I identify $1$-simplices between them?